# How many actors can be created in service fabric cluster nodes

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-actor

1. What is max no of actors in service fabric cluster
2. how does it executes concurrently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. An Actor ID is a long value, so 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 actors per `ActorType`.
2. An Actor instance executes one thread at one time by default [(single threaded execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction)).
   Multiple Actor instances can be active at the same time.